# Difference between method.getClass().newInstance() and SomeClass.class.newInstance()?

Tags: java, reflection

Recently I started messing around with reflection a little. I encountered an issue that I can't find any answer to. I'll try to explain as best as I can what the issue is.

Firstly I have a method that I got from reflection that has an annotation. When I try to invoke this method I need an instance of the class it's in ofcourse. This is what I did because it would be the easiest to do in my project:

```
method.invoke(method.getClass().newInstance(), context);
```

However, this did not work. The exception thrown with this method is **NoSuchMethodException**.
But when I tried to just get the class named *someClass* that contains the method directly it did not throw an exception and returned the method succesfully:

```
method.invoke(someClass.class.newInstance(), context);
```

I hope someone more experienced could clearify this so I could learn from this and hopefully use reflection with more ease in the future.

Thanks in advance

-DutchJelly

Comment: `method.getClass()` is getting the `Method.class` and not the class that the method belongs to. It's doing reflection on the reflection classes.

Comment: Does a method have a class? I thought it only belonged to a class.

Comment: `method` is an instance of the `Method` class. Reflection makes you treat methods as objects.

Comment: When you call method.getClass() method is an object of `java.lang.reflect.Method` class, so you you will get it. How about just try to test what does your  `method.getClass()` return?

Comment: Ah thanks. That helped me understand alot more of reflection. Maybe you could also answer the post officially so other people can see this easier. And sorry because the question probably looks stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method.getClass()` returns `Method.class`, the class object for `Method`. This is just like how e.g. `"ABC".getClass()` returns `String.class`.

What you are probably looking for is [`method.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass--).